# Wrong encoding of unpacked files

Tags: php, encoding, gzip, tar

I've got problem while unpacking *.php files. I'm unpacking archive with tar -zxvf command, and if I wont to edit some file there is a problem. Instead of polish signs there are strange strings. F.e. instead of letter ą there is something like A..: If I unpack it on windows, it works fine. How to fix it?

Comment: But the problem is not with filenames but with files content.

Comment: The file contents are not changed by the operating system: what editor are you using to look at the files in Windows, and what charset is it using?

Comment: I'm using notepad++. It autodetects coding, bug in files with polish signs it is ANSI as UTF-8. On other linux distro, where I packed that files the content is also normal. Only on another linux distro the poroblem occurs...